# How to handle wildcards in elastic search structured queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

My use case requires to query for our elastic search domain with trailing wildcards. I wanted to get your opinion on the best practices of handling such wildcards in the queries.

Do you think adding the following clauses is a good practice for the queries:

```
"query" : { 
    "query_string" : { 
        "query" :   "attribute:postfix*",
        "analyze_wildcard" : true,
        "allow_leading_wildcard" : false,
        "use_dis_max" : false
    } 
}
```

I've disallowed leading wildcards since it is a heavy operation. However I wanted to how good is analyzing wildcard for every query request in the long run. My understanding is, analyze wildcard would have no impact if the query doesn't actually have any wildcards. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the possibility of changing your mapping type and index settings, the right way to go is to create a custom analyzer with an [edge-n-gram token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) that would index all prefixes of the `attribute` field.

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/your_index -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "edge_filter": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 1,
                    "max_gram": 15
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "attr_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": ["lowercase", "edge_filter"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "your_type": {
            "properties": {
                "attribute": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "attr_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer": "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Then, when you index a document, the `attribute` field value (e.g.) `postfixing` will be indexed as the following tokens: `p`, `po`, `pos`, `post`, `postf`, `postfi`, `postfix`, `postfixi`, `postfixin`, `postfixing`.

Finally, you can then easily query the `attribute` field for the `postfix` value using a simple `match` query like this. No need to use an under-performing wildcard in a query string query.

```
{
  "query": {
     "match" : {
        "attribute" : "postfix"
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did this help? Do you need more info?