# elasticsearch full text search part of word

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I query on elasticsearch for full text searching by part of word.

For example if I have these documents

```
{
    name: "A1"
    desc: "This is first document"
}
{
    name: "A2"
    desc: "This is second document"
}
```

When I search like this

```
{
    query: {
        query_string: {
            query: 'first'
        }
    }
}
```

It returns me first document, but when I  try to search

```
{
    query: {
        query_string: {
            query: 'fir'
        }
    }
}
```

It doesnt return anything. 
How can I solve this without mapping parameters such as ngrams, just with query.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried searching with a wildcard, i.e. `fir*` ? Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use ngrams? [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706903/how-to-handle-wildcards-in-elastic-search-structured-queries)

Comment: I cant use them because how I tried they doesnt work and I cant understand why, can you check If I send them ?

Comment: Of course, feel free to create another question with the ngram issue.

Comment: @Val http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717776/ngrams-ins-elasticsearch-are-not-working

Comment: Have you tried to use the wildcard above?

Comment: Yes but I how I know wildcards cant be case insensitive.

Comment: Not sure I get you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109545/discussion-between-gor-and-val).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with a wildcard instead, like this, it will work.

```
{
    query: {
        query_string: {
            query: 'fir*'
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, [use ngrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717776/ngrams-ins-elasticsearch-are-not-working), it's much more performant.