# ngrams ins elasticsearch are not working

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I use elasticsearch ngram

```
"analysis": {
    "filter": {
        "desc_ngram": {
            "type": "ngram",
            "min_gram": 3,
            "max_gram": 8
        }
    },
    "analyzer": {
        "index_ngram": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": [ "desc_ngram", "lowercase" ]
        },
        "search_ngram": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": "lowercase"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have 2 objects here

```
{
    "name": "Shana Calandra",
    "username": "shacalandra",
},
{
    "name": "Shana Launer",
    "username": "shalauner",
},
```

And using this query

```
{
    query: {
        match: {
            _all: "Shana"
        }
    }
}
```

When I search with this query, it returns me both documents, but I cant search by part of word here, for example I cant use "Shan" instead of "Shana" in query because it doesnt return anything.

Maybe my mapping is wrong, I cant understand problem is on mapping or on query

Comment: The issue is probably that you're searching against the `_all` field and the standard analyzer is used for that field unless specified otherwise. Try matching on `name` specifically. Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify

```
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "_all": {
        "index_analyzer": "index_ngram",
        "search_analyzer": "search_ngram"
      },
```

for your mapping of `_all` field then it will work. `_all` has its own analyzers and I suspect you used the analyzers just for `name` and `username` and not for `_all`.

Comment: dont return with name or username

Comment: I don't understand what you meant.